# How To Calculate Current Value With Max Date Last Month Value

Tags: sql, db2

I have summarize daily data using a basic query and each of them need to be calculated with value of last date from previous month. Example, if I select 3 February 2022, the value should be calculated with the value from 31 January 2022.

This is my current query

```
SELECT 
    TGL, SUM(A.NOM_IDR) AS TotValue
FROM(
    SELECT 
        B.DATE AS TGL
        , (A.NOMINAL_IDR * -1) as NOM_IDR
    FROM 
        MIS.FACT_LOAN A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        MIS.DIM_PERIOD B ON A.SK_PERIOD = B.SK_PERIOD
    WHERE 
        YEAR(B.DATE) = '2022'
    )
GROUP BY TGL;
```

and the result is something like this

```
TGL        | TotValue 
2022-01-31    300000      
2022-02-01    400000      
2022-02-02    200000 
.
.
.
2022-02-26    370000 
2022-03-01    250000
```

I already trying to get the last date from each month and their TotValue with this query

```
SELECT
        B.DATE AS LASTDAYPERMONTH
        , SUM(A.NOMINAL_IDR * -1)
     FROM MIS.FACT_LOAN A
     LEFT JOIN 
        MIS.DIM_PERIOD B ON A.SK_PERIOD = B.SK_PERIOD
     INNER JOIN
        (SELECT MAX(B.DATE) AS MaxDatePerMonth
         FROM MIS.FACT_LOAN A
         LEFT JOIN 
            MIS.DIM_PERIOD B ON A.SK_PERIOD = B.SK_PERIOD
         WHERE YEAR(B.DATE) = '2022'
         GROUP BY MONTH(B.DATE)
        ) aa ON aa.MaxDatePerMonth = B.DATE
     WHERE YEAR(B.DATE) = '2022'
     GROUP BY B.DATE
```

But I dont know how to join it with my current query to achieve my desired result. Below is the example of my desired result

```
TGL        | TotValue | LastMonthValue
2022-01-31    300000         0
2022-02-01    400000      300000
2022-02-02    200000      300000
.
.
.
2022-02-26    370000      300000
2022-03-01    250000      370000
```

How can I achieve this result? Please help me to find the right query and sorry if the explanation is a bit awkward.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and add the missing information to get a [mre]

Comment: @nbk I already edit my question, is that sufficient enough? Please take a look again sir

Comment: as you see in the link we need also the original data and not onö the result

Answer (score 2):

You can first get the previous month by subtracting `INTERVAL 1 MONTH` from `now()` and then pass this as the parameter to `LAST_DAY`:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: Where can I add this query to? I updated my question can you please take a look at it again?

Comment: @HilmanDhannysworo you can add it to a select clause. For instance, instead of `TGL, SUM(A.NOM_IDR) AS TotValue` you could have `TGL, SUM(A.NOM_IDR) AS TotValue, LAST_DAY(now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS LastDayOfLastMonth`. Or you could add it to the other select, basically wherever you want it. Just make sure to ommit the `SELECT` keyword from my code if you add the last_day call as a field of an already existing select.

Comment: @HilmanDhannysworo please let me know if this works for you. If so, you might consider accepting this answer as the correct one.

Comment: I kept getting error "An unexpected toker "1" was found following.....". Is it because I'm using DB2?

Comment: @HilmanDhannysworo I do not know what query is yielding that error. Please edit your question and add your current try containing the call to `LAST_DAY`.

Comment: I'm trying your query on sqlfiddle and it works just as I need it. I think my DB2 is not supporting that function. Is there any other query that work similar to this?

Comment: @HilmanDhannysworo DB2 supports LAST_DAY: https://www.ibm.com/docs/pl/db2-for-zos/11?topic=functions-last-day

Comment: After searching here and there, I think the problem lies in the INTERVAL function and it seems it is the root cause why I can't use LAST_DAY

Comment: @HilmanDhannysworo while I have a lot of experience in MySQL, I'm much less experienced in DB2, but if you are able to use LAST_DAY in general and the `INTERVAL` keyword is the culprit, then you will need to look into date arithmetics in DB2 (see https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=sql-date-arithmetic). It seems that you can subtract a month via `- 1 MONTH` in DB2, but I did not have a chance to test this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH TAB (TGL, TotValue) AS
(
VALUES
  (DATE ('2022-01-31'),    300000)      
, (DATE ('2022-02-01'),    400000)      
, (DATE ('2022-02-02'),    200000) 
, (DATE ('2022-02-26'),    370000) 
, (DATE ('2022-03-01'),    250000)
)
SELECT 
  A.*
, COALESCE (B.TotValue, 0) AS LastMonthValue
FROM TAB A
--LEFT JOIN TAB B ON B.TGL = A.TGL - DAY (A.TGL)
LEFT JOIN TABLE
(
  SELECT B.TotValue
  FROM TAB B
  WHERE B.TGL <= A.TGL - DAY (A.TGL)
  ORDER BY B.TGL DESC
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
) B ON 1=1
ORDER BY A.TGL
```

| TGL | TOTVALUE | LASTMONTHVALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-31 | 300,000 | 0 |
| 2022-02-01 | 400,000 | 300,000 |
| 2022-02-02 | 200,000 | 300,000 |
| 2022-02-26 | 370,000 | 300,000 |
| 2022-03-01 | 250,000 | 370,000 |

The `LEFT JOIN TABLE` algorithm use gets the `LASTMONTHVALUE` value as "the last value of previous months".

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=a659f34c0175e9688c0b072c0b20a127) link.

Comment: it works! Just kinda lack in performance. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just realized that my February data only until 26th and not 28th and it causing March's LastMonthValue is 0. Is there anything that I can do to get the 26th value?

Comment: @HilmanDhannysworo look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

1. Get current date as string using DATE_FORMAT()
2. Get first day of current month using RIGHT() and CONCAT()
3. Convert string to date with STR_TO_DATE()
4. And subtract one day with INTERVAL

`

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01', RIGHT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d/%m/%Y'), 8)),'%d/%m/%Y') - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```